# Multiple Ajax Calls listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a table that gets data from 10 different sources, some of the information is pretty heavy(I store the object, clicking on table provides more information). I was trying to show the page only when loading of all information is done. My approach was to chain ajax calls by creating 10 functions and then chaining them together using .then(). It works fine, but it makes the loading time significantly longer, since now every function is waiting for another to resolve. I don't care for that,  all I need is to know when all the calls are done(in w/e order) and execute my formatting functions, hide loading modal and etc.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Updated: Here is the code:

```
$(function () {
$('#indicator').modal('show')
firstCall().then(secondCall).then(thirdCall).then(forthCall).then(fifthCall)
.then(sixthCall).then(seventhCall).then(eighthCall).then(ninthCall).then(tenthCall).then(function(){
format();
$('#indicator').modal('hide');
})})
```

and this is an example of a single function call:

```
function secondCall() {
return $.ajax({
    data: { executive: true, ex_name: 'Last_name, First_name' },
    success: function (data) {
        populate(arrange(data));
    }
})
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: can we see your code ?

Comment: Probably you can make your table more complicated and smarter. You can implement separate fillers for the table and show little progress spinner in cells which were not responded. Each request will fill specific cells you just should implement callbacks for each request and run specific filler in response.

Comment: jQuery when could end up in the same situation because each call is waiting for the other to finish which increases the time needed to load everything. Maybe try to track which have finished in an object and user setInterval to identify when all ajax calls have finished.

Comment: Sadly I am forced to use this approach, as the object that is being used must be available for immediate use, no more loading is allowed. 

I was thinking of creating flags after each call, and maybe have a function that will do something when all 10 flags are set up, only problem is how and when will this function run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer based on your replies, It got me thinking about 'when' and I realized it has an interesting way of working. So since I handle data from ajax calls separately in each function, all I had to do was this:

```
$(function () {
  $('#indicator').modal('show')
    $.when(firstCall(),secondCall(),thirdCall(),forthCall(),fifthCall(),sixthCall(), 
         seventhCall(), eighthCall(), ninthCall(), tenthCall()).done(function(){
            format();
            $('#indicator').modal('hide');
         })
})
```